# Does music app Sayonara work with Media Player indicator?

Tags: music-player, media-buttons

I am considering switching from mac to Ununtu.

My question is about music app Sayonara; Does that also work with Media Player Indicator?

Thanx for the answers! ;-)

Sayonara Player – small, clear and fast audio player
https://www.linuxlinks.com/sayonara-player-small-clear-fast-audio-player/

Media Player Indicator Is A Slick Sound Menu for GNOME Shell
https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/09/gnome-shell-music-player-extension